# how to define column type in golang type struct as longtext?

Tags: go, martini

I have this peace of code:

```
type Post struct {
    Id      int64 `db:"post_id"`
    Created int64
    Title   string `form:"Title"`
    Body    string `form:"Body" binding:"required"`

}
```

but that gets me only 255 varchar for Body.
How can i set that to be longtext?

This is from example app for martini framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maximum length of a string in go is definitely way bigger than 255. If you will look at [this code](http://play.golang.org/p/k8XRgad0pv):

```
myPost := Post{
  Id: 43,
  Created: 324,
  Title: "title",
  Body: "very long string",
}
fmt.Println(myPost.Body)
fmt.Println()
fmt.Println(len(myPost.Body))
```

you will see that the output of a string and the length is clearly bigger than 255. So either you are saving it to database, which truncates it, or I would rather create a nice reproducible example.

Comment: so there is no way that i can use dbmap.AddTableWithName(Post{}, "posts").SetKeys(true, "Id") and have longtext? i have to define database tables first?